# SSRS - change location of "View Report" button

Tags: reporting-services

The View Report button is right aligned.  How I can I make it left aligned in a report?

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e51d7a1b-83e4-4c8c-99c7-0607d3a02917/customize-toolbar-on-ssrs-report-server?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and help.  Where in the  ReportingServices.css file is the View Report element so I may change its location please?